# Akka Java File IO Throttling

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I want to stream file content line by line to Actor. I have something like that:

```
final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("stream_system");
final Materializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);
final ActorRef actor = system.actorOf(Props.create(streamActor.class), "sink");

final Path file = Paths.get("path/file.txt");

Sink<ByteString, CompletionStage<Done>> printlnSink =
        Sink.<ByteString> foreach(chunk -> actor.tell(chunk.utf8String(), null));
        //Sink.<ByteString> actorRef(actor, null);

CompletionStage<IOResult> ioResult =
        FileIO.fromPath(file)
                .throttle(1, Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), 1, ThrottleMode.shaping())
                .to(printlnSink)
                .run(materializer);
```

Uncommented version works, but it streams whole file content in one go. Commented version ends up with "unknown" messages.

I want to send line by line to Actor with few seconds delay. Any help how to accomplish this? Receiving actor just take String message and print it on output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Framing`](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/javadsl/Framing.html) class can help you with this:

```
CompletionStage<IOResult> ioResult =
    FileIO.fromPath(file)
          .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString.fromString(System.lineSeparator()), 1000, FramingTruncation.ALLOW))
          .throttle(1, Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), 1, ThrottleMode.shaping())
          .to(printlnSink)
          .run(materializer);
```